# Position fixed seems to work like position absolute in IE10 Mobile ONLY

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I have a div positioned to te top right of my page like so:

```
position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 25px;
```

This works on all browsers and devices except IE10 Mobile, here it behaves just like a position absolute would do on any other browser.

On the screenshot below you see how it shows on most browsers:
[image: desired functionality]

The following screenshot shows the position: absolute behavior. (same as IE10 Mobile does)

[image: IE Mobile behavior]

Comment: I tested on: IE9, IE10, IE10 Mobile, Android Chrome, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, iOS Safari. It only occurs on IE10 Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it's a bug still not solved by Microsoft. There's a workaround to this problem though (not a pretty one)

First of all detect the IE10 Mobile browser (there are several ways to do this so I'll not post this bit). Then for this browser, apply this part of javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var allFixed = $('*').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('position') == 'fixed';
  });
  allFixed.each(function() {
     $(this).detach();
     $('body').append($(this));
     var top = parseInt($(this).css('top'), 10) + scrollTop;
     $(this).css({ 'top': top+'px' });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing "height" declaration. Please, look at this [How to make a fixed div in IE10 Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185811/how-to-make-a-fixed-div-in-ie10-mobile). Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, I have the height set.